# How can I send an array of url to a function on AWS EC2 from my shared hosting?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I have my site on a shared hosting and using AWS SDK PHP.

I have urls in my database on the shared and want to send them to a function on Amazon EC2. Is it possible to send them in an array?

I have this scenario

1. I grab the links from the database on my shared hosting when the user clicks on a link and put them in an array or something (This is no problem).
2. I want to send this links to a function on EC2 (this i my problem).
3. Do some stuff with the links on EC2 when I have them in an array or something (This is no problem).

Edit

Found that I can use html form $_POST. But is there a better solution?